wait for async event to occur before exiting the tests
I have a component that dispatches an event on load. The listener is outside the component, in this case a Unit Test listening to the event.
const User = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('mounted', {detail: {foo: "bar"}}));
  }, [])
}


Attempt - bubbles property didn't work
component
const User = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('mounted', { bubbles: true, detail: {foo: "bar"}}));
  }, [])
}

Unit Test
it("should get event", () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => { // return promise so runner waits on it.
        console.log('promise'); // called
        window.addEventListener("mounted", event => {
            console.log("listener"); // not called
            expect(event.detail.foo).equal("bar");
            resolve();
        });

        act(() => {
            render(<UserList />);
        });
    });
});


Personally i'd spyOn the dispatchEvent and assert if it has been called (ideally assert what did it call with). Then do cleanup() and assert if it has been called for the 2nd time.

oh there's some data that I want to assert on as I receive the event in the unit test. so just spying is not an option.

@TaiweiTuan any further ideas? Please have another look at the question.

It looks like you expect your event to bubble up the chain of nodes. You should mention it explicitly when creating the event:
let evtMounted = new CustomEvent('mounted', {
     bubbles: true,
     detail: "some value, different for each SUT"
});
dispatchEvent(evtMounted);
return () => {
  evtUnmounted = new CustomEvent('unmounted', { bubbles: true });
  dispatchEvent(evtUnmounted);
}

link to MDN post: event bubbling

That's for the attempt, I felt this was promising but no success. please see my attempt (edit section), to get closer to what I wanted.

My mistake, I made a typo. The {bubbles: ..., detail: ... } object should be passed to the CustomEvent() constructor, not to dispatchEvent(). Fixed.

Irrespective of the typo, I followed it correctly but the expectations are not met. Can you please try this in a unit test? dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("mounted", {bubbles: true, detail: {foo: "bar"}}));

any other ideas?

can you please also upvote this question, not sure who did it without explaining on a valid and difficult question.
